# Having issues creating a SOCKS5 Proxy. Can not Tunnel device

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, port-forwarding, socks5

I have a desktop machine in my home which ive turned into a Ubuntu (desktop 14 LTS) SSH server using OPENssh. I can SSH into my machine locally using public key authentication (&Putty from my win8.1 laptop) and form outside my LAN without issues. I am trying to create an SSH tunnel (dynamic port forward) to my home PC but i keep receiving errors while attempting to connect. I have been following this write up: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding and i have consulted many others.

After my SSH connection to my home PC authenticates im calling the command

```
ssh -D 1080 dell
```

*dell is the name of my windows 8.1 laptop im using with putty to connect to my SSH server

If i am on my LAN i get an error after the connection times out which reads

```
ssh: connect to host dell port 22: Connection timed out
```

So in my testing i tried connecting outside my home network and received a similar error

```
ssh: connect to host dell port 22: No rout to host
```

Ive also tried

```
ssh -D 1080 userName@IP.of.SSHserver
```

This will give me an authentication error. If i say "yes" to connect then i get a "Permission denied (publickey)." error

At this point im unsure if my syntax is correct in my ssh -D command or if my problem is elsewhere. I have double checked my sshd_config file as well and i do have my config file set up with AllowTcpForwarding yes & X11Forwarding yes

Any help into diagnosing this issue is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I was able to get my connection to work using `ssh -D 1080 userName@IP.of.SSHserver` once i configured Putty correctly. I was using Pageant to initially log in and since i did not specify to putty where my public key was the authentication for dynamic port forwarding was failing.

However im still unable to make a tunneled connection. I keep receiving error: `tunnel device open failed. Could not request tunnel forwarding.` I keep looking over my ssh_config & sshd_config files and can not find any issues...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my log from ssh -vvv -D 1080 user@IP

```
    OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 107.000.000.000 [107.000.000.000] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key': No such file or directory
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/arron/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "107.000.000.000" from file "/home/arron/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/arron/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 89:59:45:3f:70:e.......................
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "107.000.000.000" from file "/home/arron/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/arron/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '107.000.000.000' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/arron/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: rsa-key-20150212 (0x7f44db1a8d40),
debug2: key: /home/arron/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/arron/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/arron/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/arron/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: rsa-key-20150212
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 533
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 95:3b:a0:0f:4d:b6:09:3.....................
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 95:3b:a0:0f:4d:b6:09:3.......................
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 107.000.000.000 ([107.000.000.000]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1080.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1080.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting tun unit 2147483647 in mode 1

debug1: sys_tun_open: failed to configure tunnel (mode 1): Operation not permitted
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 2
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 2: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 2: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 2
```

Comment: Bump. Anyone have any ideas?